# Naming convention for delete in spring-data

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

The spring-data-jdbc:3.0.3 documentation states that in order to generated queries based on function names, one needs to provide a [keyword](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#appendix.query.method.subject) and some [predicate modifiers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#appendix.query.method.predicate).

For example `existsByIdAndOwner` will return true if there is a record for which the provided Id and Owner match. Also `deleteById` will delete a record based on the provided Id. But `deleteByIdAndOwner` doesn't seem to work. I tried the following combinations.

```
public interface EntityRepository extends CrudRepository<Entity, Long> {

    Entity findByIdAndOwner(Long id, String owner);       // works

    boolean existsByIdAndOwner(Long id, String owner);    // works

    void deleteById(Long id);                             // work

    void deleteByIdAndOwner(Long id, String owner);       // doesn't work

    void deleteEntityByIdAndOwner(Long id, String owner); // doesn't work

    void removeByIdAndOwner(Long id, String owner);       // doesn't work

    void removeEntityByIdAndOwner(Long id, String owner); // doesn't work
}
```

Is thera a way to generate a delete query based on function name, that take two predicates into account?

Comment: the link you share about [keyword](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#appendix.query.method.subject), says that `deleteBy` and `removeBy` will `Delete query method returning either no result (void) or the delete count.`. What does it mean it doesn't work? Are you getting an error at **compilation** time? during **runtime**? could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?